# Query slow after execute DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have 2 tables Called `"Users(60,0000 records),UserBasicInfo(60,0000 records)"`,The Users table have a clustered index on UsersID column.The UserBasicInfo table have a UsersID FK point to Users table UsersID column
and have Non-clustered on `UpdateTime,UsersID` column.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Users](
    [UsersID] [int] IDENTITY(100000,1) NOT NULL,
    [LoginUsersName] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [LoginUsersPwd] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Email] [nvarchar](80) NOT NULL,
    [IsEnable] [int] NOT NULL,
    [CreateTime] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [LastLoginTime] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [LastLoginIp] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [UpdateTime] [datetime] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Users] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [UsersID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UserBasicInfo](
    [UserBaicInfoID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [UsersID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ResumePoints] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [IsChineseOrEnglish] [int] NOT NULL,
    [UserName] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Sex] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Height] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Birthday] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [Age] [int] NOT NULL,
    [IDCard] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [IsMarryed] [int] NOT NULL,
    [NativePlace] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [PoliticalStatus] [int] NOT NULL,
    [CurrentAddress] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [CurrentAddressDetail] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [WorkExperience] [int] NOT NULL,
    [HighestEducation] [int] NOT NULL,
    [LogoPath] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
    [MobilePhone] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Phone] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [QQ] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Blog] [nvarchar](300) NULL,
    [MicroBlog] [nvarchar](300) NULL,
    [PositionDesired] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [IndustrySmallClass] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [PositionName] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [PositionType] [int] NOT NULL,
    [WorkAddressLarge] [int] NOT NULL,
    [WorkAddressSmall] [nvarchar](200) NOT NULL,
    [WorkAddressSmallText] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [Salary] [int] NOT NULL,
    [HousingRequirement] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ToWorkTime] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ResumeState] [int] NOT NULL,
    [IsSystemAdd] [int] NOT NULL,
    [CreateTime] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [UpdateTime] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [RefreshDateTime] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [RefreshTime] [int] NOT NULL,
    [TotalTime] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_UserBasicInfo] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [UserBaicInfoID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[UserBasicInfo]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_UserBasicInfo_Users] FOREIGN KEY([UsersID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Users] ([UsersID])
```

But execute below slow:

```
DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS   
DBCC FREEPROCCACHE
SELECT TOP 100 * FROM Users U INNER JOIN UserBasicInfo UB ON UB.UsersID=U.UsersID ORDER BY UB.UpdateTime DESC

SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 16 ms,  elapsed time = 3568 ms.
```

[image]
Then execute below fast:

```
SELECT TOP 100 * FROM Users U INNER JOIN UserBasicInfo UB ON UB.UsersID=U.UsersID ORDER BY UB.UpdateTime DESC

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 163 ms.
```

[image]

It is normal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is normal

Your 2 DBCC commands ahve removed query plans and cached data. Data has to be read from disk again which is probably the main overhead.

If you add [`SET STATISTICS IO ON`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184361.aspx) you'll see more "physical page reads" and "read-ahead reads" after the DBCC as data is loaded from disk

I almost never run them. For more, see these dba.se questions

- https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/10820/630
- https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/7859/630